# Is this image a Manifold?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

I need some help with this exercise.

Let $g:]-\pi/2,\pi/2[ \to R^2, \Theta \to \sin(\Theta)\cos(\Theta)(\cos(\Theta),\sin(\Theta))$.

Now let $M$ be the image of $g$.

I'm asked to decide, wether M is a submanifold or not.

There is a hint which told me to look how many components a small enough neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ in $M$ without $(0,0)$ has.

The answer should be two, as i can write the neigbourhood as a union of the $(x,y)$ which are right of $(0,0)$ and the values $(-x,y)$ which are at the opposite site.

I'm not sure how to procceed, has anyone (another) hint for me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Umm,intervals are connected, continuous images of connected sets are connected so certainly this is the case for $\mathcal{C}^K$ maps. If you assume $M = g(X = (-\pi/2, \pi/2))$ is a sub-manifold then your map $g: X \to M  \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a local diffeomorphism and so by invariance of domain,

$$\textbf{dim}(M) = \textbf{dim}(X) = 1$$

Hence, $g$ should be a local diffeomorphism onto $(0,0)$. You showed that $M$ has two components at $(0,0)$ i.e you can think of $M = (a,b) \cup (b,c)$. Thus, $g|_{X':=X \setminus g^{-1}(0,0)} : X' \to M\setminus \{(0,0)\} $ is not a local diffeomorphism, but it should be since it is just a restriction.

Comment: Thank you for this answer :)

Comment: There is still one point which i didn't understand. You argue that a connected set should be mapped onto a connected set by a diffemorphism.. but the set $X'$ isn't connected aswell and I don't see where then is the contradiction. Could you please help me out once again ?